# I want to measure 50 miliamps by multimeter which range i should select?

Tags: multimeter

I have a multi meter I want to measure DC 1-50 milliamps which range I should select by the knob?

Also where I need to plug in 20A or mA?

[image]

Comment: I am curious if you read the manual yet?

Comment: @Transistor And it is quite a short manual! With things like "The 20A range is not protected by a fuse and has a maximum 10A continuous current rating." that should be in read, blinking and with a loud buzzer... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 200m setting from the orange section with an A with a solid and dotted bar above. You can find the manual for the meter [here.](http://datasheetcafe.databank.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/DT9205A-Manual.pdf)

Comment: I need to plug the red wire to 20A or mA socket ?

Comment: mA. Please take some time to read the linked manual. You can damage your device by connecting it wrongly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. Much appreciated.

Comment: mA and COM, see the manual.